# Oracle database 12g user does not exist

Tags: oracle12c

I have a Oracle Database 12C and, when i do the following query on SYS schema

```
select * from all_users;
```

i get listed USER_X.

However, when i try to alter USER_X's password, by doing the following

```
ALTER USER USER_X IDENTIFIED BY XPTO_123;
```

i get the error

```
SQL Error: ORA-01918: 01918. 00000 -  "user '%s' does not exist"
```

Am i missing something?

Thanks

Comment: What is the actual value for User_X?>

Comment: Have you committed the data?

Comment: @KalharaAmarasinghe - what the heck are you talking about? What "data" must be committed?

Comment: I had a similar problem where my sql queries  executed through sqldeveloper was not actually commited to the database.When i view through sqldeveloper it is visible but when viewd from  sql plus its not since autocommit was disabled in sqldeveloper.Anyway gave a suggestion and maybe I am wrong.Nevertheless I do not think your sentence should start with "what the heck".If you think I am wrong,there are polite ways to say that.

Answer (score 0):

How was the 12C database installed? Does it uses the "Multitenant" architecture?
If so, alter the user's password may differ for CDB and PDB.
You can refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4003.htm#SQLRF01103) and [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html) links for more infos.